# Accessing MongoDB Atlas using Monk

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-atlas, monk

To access a database at MongoDB Atlas using Node.js, there exists an [official guideline, which uses the mongodb package](https://cloud.mongodb.com/v2/5d0095d0f2a30b5c7d18852a#clusters/connect?clusterId=Cluster0):

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const uri = "mongodb+srv://<user>:<password>@cluster0-b8teo.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority";
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useNewUrlParser: true });
client.connect(err => {
  const collection = client.db("test").collection("devices");
  // perform actions on the collection object
  client.close();
});
```

How can the same be done with the [monk package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/monk)?

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to MongoDB Atlas using Monk package similary how you do with mongoose or with nodejs-mongo client.

package dependencies

```
"mongodb": "^3.2.7",
"monk": "^7.0.0",
```

Connection

```
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var monk = require('monk');
var db = monk(`connectionstring`);
db.then(() =>{
  console.log("connection success");
}).catch((e)=>{
  console.error("Error !",e);
});
```

Connection string I used, I had three replica sets
`mongodb://username:strongpassword@replicaset1:27017,replicaset2:27017,replicaset3:27017/dbname?ssl=true&replicaSet=replicateSetName&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority`

You could get this connection string from MongoDB Atlas. Select your app -> connections -> nodejs -> select your version.

Hope this helps you!